# How large rectangles fit on canvas

Tags: discrete-mathematics, applications

I have `images` whose side ratios are known, and the number of `images` is known. I have `canvas` whose measurements are known. I need to know what's the optimal length of `images` sides so that all my `images` would fit on `canvas` and maximum area is used.
All `images` are of the same size. And `images` should be placed correctly for viewing. (not on a side that would make image horizont be in vertical angle.)

I put the question under discrete-mathematics, let me know if it's in a wrong place.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Are images and canvas all rectangles?

Comment: yes they are all rectangles

Comment: If you allow the images to be really small then we can always fit perfectly. Let the width and height of canvas be $w$ and $h$ and the ratio of image width over height be $p\over q$ then let $t={gcd(w,h)\over pq}$ and let the width of image be $pt$ and height of image be $qt$. (Assuming you can zoom the image to any rational number)

Comment: what's `ged` function? =)

Comment: The greatest common divisor.

Comment: but this doesn't take into account that I could have 1 image and 5 images. If there is one it should fit 100% on one axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link had (Almost) the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643129/split-screen-based-on-number-of-items-and-screen-ratio

> // Set this to the desired x-to-y ratio. const preferred_ratio = 1.2;
>
> function calc_cols_rows(In: screen, In: num_items, Out: num_rows, Out:
> num_cols) {   desired_aspect = (screen.width / screen.height) /
> preferred_ratio;
>
> // Calculate the number of rows that is closest to the desired
> aspect:
>
> num_rows = round(sqrt(num_items / desired_aspect));
>
> // Calculate the required number of columns:
>
> num_cols =
> ceil(num_items / num_rows); }

Answer (score 1):

I found a neat implementation to a similar question from [Neptilo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2570649/722611). It didn't work for rectangles though, only squares. So I applied the idea from [mckeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480939/1318145) to normalise the rectangle and then follow the algorithm for squares.

The result is the `fitToContainer()`  function. Give it the number of rectangles to fit `n`, the `containerWidth` and `containerHeight` and the original `itemWidth` and `itemHeight`. In case items have no original width and height, use `itemWidth` and `itemHeight` to specify the desired ratio of the items.

For example `fitToContainer(10, 1920, 1080, 16, 9)` results in `{nrows: 4, ncols: 3, itemWidth: 480, itemHeight: 270}`, so four columns and 3 rows of 480 x 270 (pixels, or whatever the unit is).

And to fit 10 squares in the same example area of 1920x1080 you could call `fitToContainer(10, 1920, 1080, 1, 1)` resulting in `{nrows: 2, ncols: 5, itemWidth: 384, itemHeight: 384}`.

```
function fitToContainer(n, containerWidth, containerHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight) {
    // We're not necessarily dealing with squares but rectangles (itemWidth x itemHeight),
    // temporarily compensate the containerWidth to handle as rectangles
    containerWidth = containerWidth * itemHeight / itemWidth;
    // Compute number of rows and columns, and cell size
    var ratio = containerWidth / containerHeight;
    var ncols_float = Math.sqrt(n * ratio);
    var nrows_float = n / ncols_float;

    // Find best option filling the whole height
    var nrows1 = Math.ceil(nrows_float);
    var ncols1 = Math.ceil(n / nrows1);
    while (nrows1 * ratio < ncols1) {
        nrows1++;
        ncols1 = Math.ceil(n / nrows1);
    }
    var cell_size1 = containerHeight / nrows1;

    // Find best option filling the whole width
    var ncols2 = Math.ceil(ncols_float);
    var nrows2 = Math.ceil(n / ncols2);
    while (ncols2 < nrows2 * ratio) {
        ncols2++;
        nrows2 = Math.ceil(n / ncols2);
    }
    var cell_size2 = containerWidth / ncols2;

    // Find the best values
    var nrows, ncols, cell_size;
    if (cell_size1 < cell_size2) {
        nrows = nrows2;
        ncols = ncols2;
        cell_size = cell_size2;
    } else {
        nrows = nrows1;
        ncols = ncols1;
        cell_size = cell_size1;
    }

    // Undo compensation on width, to make squares into desired ratio
    itemWidth = cell_size * itemWidth / itemHeight;
    itemHeight = cell_size;
    return { nrows: nrows, ncols: ncols, itemWidth: itemWidth, itemHeight: itemHeight }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to resize an image of size $l_1 \times w_1$ in a canvas sized $L \times W$. Then your scale factor to maximize the resized image allows one of its dimensions to reach the canvas dimension.

Thus we find a scale factor $s=Min(L/l_1,W/w_1)$ and a resized image of dimensions $l_2 \times w_2 = l_1 \cdot s \times w_1 \cdot s$.

- If the length to width ratio of the image is larger than the canvas, then the length dimension will be filled $l_2 = l_1 \cdot s = l_1 \cdot L/l_1 = L$.
- Otherwise, the width dimension will be filled $w_2 = w_1 \cdot s = w_1 \cdot W/w_1 = W$.

For multiple images aligned in a M*N rectangular fashion, swap $l_1$ and $w_1$ for $M \cdot l_1$ and $N \cdot w_1$. For any other adjustment, find the dimensions of the whole merged  group and apply the same rules as if it was a single (bigger) image.

Comment: Had similar idea. I'ill try to implement this idea in few days. :)

Comment: Did this method meet your expectations or were you looking for something else ?

Comment: I know the number of images. But I don't know the M and N values :D

Comment: Found the answer thanks for help!